# Is Photo Gallery Slideshow JSON readable by Google

Tags: json, gallery, slideshow, hybrid

We have a hybrid slideshow, meaning, each slide has its own unique URL, yet you can click through the whole slideshow without refreshing the page. In order to achieve that, we have a JSON living on each unique URL with info of all other slides, such as headers, subheaders, captions and image URL's.

Would that affect SEO negatively? Would Google read the JSON? And if so, would they read it as redundant data?

Answer (score 0):

At current, this "one-page" architecture will negatively impact your ability to rank on Google.

Here are two public perceptions of how Google handles javascript:

1) Google can crawl some content served with javascript however does not prioritize it as highly in SERPs (search engine results pages) as content served across plain html pages.

Some technologies like screen readers (used by the blind) do not process javascript effectively and limit applications of this nature from achieving penetration to greater than 95% of the internet-connected population.

2) Google can crawl javascript but they have not yet weighed it into their algorithm because their technology has not yet fully matured.

I personally am with the first camp and believe that javascript sites won't be considered as highly in SERPS until ancillary web-browsing technologies supporting niche population groups have excellent support for javascript.

Only time will tell :)

Comment: Thanks Dave, and yeah I agree, but it's about finding the balance between SEO and UX. Each gallery would view ok without the JS though and you'd be able to see all slide. 

My concern is that if the JSON with the info of all slide is on each crawlable slide, and each crawlable slide has a unique URL, then would google read that JSON and count it as redundant data, and therefore rank us low.

Comment: On the crawlable pages, use schema.org constructs and you'll be safe from duplicate content worries.  These are quite effective at indicating to search engines (and other crawlers) what is unique about each page/slide.  Takes a bit to implement but well worth the effort in the long term.  Check out the src at [tsuvo.com](http://tsuvo.com) and see how we've used them.